# Animate color on mouseenter (and revert back to original color on mouseleave)

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.group-overlay').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var precolor;
        if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
            var precolor = jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml').css("color");
            jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml, .group-logo').animate({
                color: "#FFFFFF",
                top: "+=40",
            }, 300, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        } else if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
            jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml, .group-logo').animate({
                color: "'" + precolor + "'",
                top: "-=40",
            }, 300, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So basically there are boxes you can hover, some have font color black, some are white. On nouseenter they all need to go white, on mouseleave they need to go back to their original color. I have tried the above and tried setting the text color to initial on mouseleave but no matter what I do they stay white on mouseleave (where as the original black fonts should go back to black on mouseleave.

If you have a look at this quick [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/316rhwhr/) I made it will make it a bit clearer than me trying to explain, thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for any JS code here, you can achieve all this in CSS alone:

```css
.test-service {
    transition: padding 0.5s;
    /* other properties... */
}

.group-overlay:hover + .test-service {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.group-overlay:hover + .test-service .txt-sml {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/316rhwhr/6/)

Comment: What a simple and elegant solution. +1

Comment: Ya elegant just depending [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) needed. BTW, `transition: all` is not that elegant :)

Comment: @A.Wolff good point, that was me being lazy :) Updated to just `transition: padding 0.5s`

Comment: Great solution, I was going to do it like this initially but there are some other bits going on that I can't do with CSS so I figured it would be best to do it all using jQuery. In regards to the specific question, this is the better solution as jQuery is not needed. +1

Answer (score 2):

The value of `precolor` must be outside from the `mouseenter mouseleave` action.
if you put it in the `mouseenter mouseleave` action, it will getting non-existing color when you mouseleave.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var precolor;
  jQuery('.group-overlay').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
      precolor = jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml').css("color");
      jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml, .group-logo').animate({
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        top: "+=40",
      }, 300, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    } else if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
    console.log(precolor);
      jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml, .group-logo').animate({
        color: "'" + precolor + "'",
        top: "-=40",
      }, 300, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: but you should use Rory McCrossan solution which is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Using your initial code sample:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var precolor = "";
    jQuery('.group-overlay').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        precolor = jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml').css("color");
        jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml, .group-logo').animate({
          color: "#FFFFFF",
          top: "+=40",
        }, 300, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        jQuery(this).next('.test-service').find('.txt-sml, .group-logo').animate({
          color: "'" + precolor + "'",
          top: "-=40",
        }, 300, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
    });
});
```

[Demo jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/316rhwhr/8/)